# "Gets dizzy" and comma splice when multiple events happen

Tags: grammaticality, commas

> Kevin gets dizzy, his sight blurs, and he falls.

Is the comma splice okay? Is the phrase "gets dizzy" grammatically correct? Is anything else wrong with above sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is listing three different actions, in the same way the following sentences do.

> I had dinner, brushed my teeth, and went to sleep.

> I went to the store, Michelle returned home, and Maria waited for her husband to return home.

The comma before *and* is the [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_comma) used in a list of three or more items before *and* or *or*.

Grammatically, there isn't anything wrong with *get dizzy*, in the same way there isn't anything wrong with *get hungry*, *get sick*, or *get frustrated*.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a comma splice.  It's a list of three things:

> A, B, and C.

Notice the *and* before the last item.  A comma splice looks more like the following:

> A, B.

Anyway, your sentence is grammatical.  Nothing is particularly wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Get is one of those words that is hard for ESL speakers, because it has many definitions (get dizzy, get home, get money, get a point), is often used idiomatically (get on one's nerves, get wind of) and is often combined with a preposition to form a phrasal verb (get at, get by, get along).  For a list, see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get.